# Fetch the selected value from scale toolbar

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, php, jquery

[image]

can somebody guide me how to fetch that value shown in the image? using jquery and or PHP language?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenLayers the map holds that information so a call to [`map.getScale()`](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getScale) will return the current scale denominator of the map.  If no baselayer is set, returns null. All you need to do is put "1:" in front of it.